# Unexpected result from simple lambda function in list comprehension

Tags: python

Note:  Using Python 3.11.5 on Windows 11 (x64)

```py
# Input:
items = [['fish:', '2'], ['cats:', '3'], ['dogs:', '5']]

# Goal - convert to dictionary, strip ':' from word, convert string to int:
# e.g., {'fish': 2, 'cats': 3, 'dogs': 5}
# Approach - use list comprehension with lambda (this is only part of the solution):
[(lambda item: item[0].strip(':'), int(item[1])) for item in items]

# Unexpected output:
[(<function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x00000185D4D51620>, 2), (<function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x00000185D7239D00>, 3), ...]

# The lambda works - I can even add the following:
[(lambda item: item[0].strip(':'), item[0].strip(':'), int(item[1])) for item in items]
[(<function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x00000185D4810C20>, 'fish', 2), ...]
```

Why is the first item in the tuple returned by the lambda what appears to be a function?  I could come up with other ways to solve this.  However, I have not encountered this kind of behavior from a lambda before, and I would like to understand what's going on.

Comment: *"Why is the first item in the tuple returned by the lambda what appears to be a function?"* Because `(lambda item: item[0].strip(':'), int(item[1]))` **is** a function. You probably want something like `[(lambda item: item[0].strip(':'), int(item[1]))(i) for i in items]`, where the function is applied to argument `i`, or `list(map(lambda item: (item[0].strip(':'), int(item[1])), items))`.

Comment: If you want `item[0].strip(':')` to be the first element of your tuple, _make that the first element of your tuple!_ You make a _lambda_ that does the same thing, but never call it. Also just use a dict comprehension like the answers say

Comment: @slothrop Thanks!  That's so obvious now that you point it out, I don't know how I missed that.  One thing though - I couldn't get it to work quite like you said.  I had to add parenthesis around the tuple:  [(lambda item: (item[0].strip(':'), int(item[1])))(item) for item in items].  Without enclosing the tuple in the lambda in parentheses, I get a TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable.  Thanks for helping me figure it out.

Comment: No problem, sorry for my parentheses error! Glad it was enough of a hint to get you going nevertheless :)

Comment: @pho You're right - I'm making it needlessly complicated.  I don't know what I was thinking this morning as there are much better and simpler ways to solve this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for lambda here. A dictionary comprehension will suffice.

If you know that the first string in each sublist ends with ':' then:

```
d = {k[:-1]: int(v) for k, v in items}
```

If the first string in each sublist *may* end with ':' then:

```
d = {k.rstrip(':'): int(v) for k, v in items}
```

If you want to remove all leading or trailing ':' then:

```
d = {k.strip(':'): int(v) for k, v in items}
```

Comment: Thanks - this is a better solution.  I was curious what I did wrong with the embedded lambda.  I just forgot to call it and I didn't realize you need to wrap the returned tuple in parentheses (you don't in a normal function).  Also - nice touch with rstrip, that's really a better option since in this case the text to strip out will only be on the right.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using a dict comprehension

```
>>> items = [['fish:', '2'], ['cats:', '3'], ['dogs:', '5']]
>>> {i[0][:-1]: int(i[1]) for i in items}
{'fish': 2, 'cats': 3, 'dogs': 5}
```

In your current list comprehension you are actually just *defining* a list of lambda functions, instead of executing their logic to create new values.

Comment: You're right, somehow I missed the obvious and defined it without invoking it.  Thanks for the reply.